# Session ID Changes on Every Request: Next.js with Express.js Backend

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, next-auth

I have Next.js v14 for frontend and Express.js for backend. I want to auth guard to some route on Next.js so I have used `middleware.ts`

```
export default async function middleware(request: Request) {
  const loginStatus = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/auth/loginstatus', {
    credentials: 'include',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  });
  const loginStatusJson = await loginStatus.json();
  console.log(loginStatusJson);
  if (loginStatusJson && !loginStatusJson.status) {
    return NextResponse.redirect('http://localhost:3000/login');
  }
}
```

In Express.js I have used session

```
app.use(
  session({
    secret: '1234567890QWERTY',
    resave: false,
    store: new MemoryStore(),
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
      secure: false,
    },
  }),
);
```

But, from `middleware.ts` on every request I am encountering a different `sessionId`, and If I get different `sessionId` on every request how can I authenticate a user!

`middleware.ts` response was like following:

```
{
  message: 'You are not logged in!',
  status: false,
  session: 'DS3aPROFxqVDo5_sHGB6Nos7ei6FY5cp'
}

{
  message: 'You are not logged in!',
  status: false,
  session: 'kJTFATQHHcbukbsaPGo-WmfExl_rjCnj'
}

{
  message: 'You are not logged in!',
  status: false,
  session: 'MXOhNFSkCPDYrZnBJBmAgjfV3Vgpkc4Y'
}

...
```

I want to know why the `sessionId` is changing on every request?

From the front-end(client component) session is working perfectly. But, when I tried with server component whether it is `middleware.ts` or next.js `/api` on every request I am getting different `sessionID` I think the origin get changed from server component on every request!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get sessionId change is you make a request from the nextjs using server action or from nextjs route api. if the request from nextjs server, make sure you get cookie from the next/header and when fetch attach the cookie to the header. If make request on client, cookie attach automatic.

Sample below:

```
 'use server';
import { RequestOptions, http, utils } from '@/helpers';
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';

export async function signupAction<T>(options: RequestOptions = {}) {
  const sid = cookies().get('connect.sid');

  const fullUrl = utils.stringifyUrl(
    `${process.env.API_URL}/auth/signup`,
    options?.params
  );

  // Add the cookie to the request headers if available
  const headers = sid
    ? {
        ...options.headers,
        Cookie: `${sid.name}=${sid.value}`,
      }
    : options.headers;

  console.log(headers);

  return fetch(fullUrl, { ...options, headers });
}
```